# Binary interoperability between gzdecode() and inflate_add()

Tags: php, websocket, zlib, php-7, deflate

I wrote a small WebSocket library a while back, and found adding gzip support surprisingly easy. I didn't fully realize at the time that the `deflate_init()` / `deflate_add()` / `inflate_init()` / `inflate_add()` functions were actually PHP 7-only, and now I'd like to be able to run my WebSocket server under PHP 5 environments.

My problem is, `deflate_add()` produces output that differs slightly from `gzdeflate()` - by one character in the testcase below.

**The `deflate_add()`/`inflate_add()`-based approach works perfectly in-browser,** so the output of `gzdeflate()` is the incorrect one. I'm guessing `gzdeflate()`/`gzinflate()` are using zlib with different underlying options - something related to stream state, maybe? - and that's causing everything to fall apart.

Ultimately I want to know if I can convince PHP 5-era zlib functions to output "correct" deflated data.

---

First of all, the `deflate_init()`/`deflate_add()`-based approach I used on PHP 7:

```php
$data = "ABC";

$ctx = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW);

// unfortunately I can't find the gigantic blog post with example code
// that I learned from :(, but it contained the Ruby equivalent of the
// the substr() below. I blinked at it a bit but apparently this is how
// it's done.
$deflated = substr(deflate_add($ctx, $data, ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH), 0, -4);

// $deflated is now "rtr\6\0"

$ictx = inflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW);

$data2 = inflate_add($ictx, $deflated, ZLIB_NO_FLUSH);

// $data2 is now "ABC"
```

Here's what happens if I use `gzdeflate()`/`gzinflate()`:

```php
$data = "ABC";

$deflated = gzdeflate($data, 9, ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW);

// $deflated is now "str\6\0"

$output = gzinflate($deflated);

// $output is now "ABC"
```

Trying to `gzinflate()` the output of `inflate_add()` produces a *`data error`*. As a TL;DR:

```php
print gzinflate("rtr\6\0")."\n"; // will bomb out

print gzinflate("str\6\0")."\n"; // prints "ABC"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling correct is incorrect, and what you are calling incorrect is correct.

With `deflate_add` you are deliberately creating an unterminated, i.e. invalid, deflate stream. Why, I have no idea. (Nor, apparently, do you, since this came from a "gigantic blog post" that you cannot find.) This is being done with the `ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH` which completes the current deflate block and appends an empty stored block. The `substr(,,-4)` is removing most of that empty stored block at the end, leaving you with an incomplete, invalid inflate stream, prematurely ending in the middle of a stored block.

`gzdeflate` on the other hand is creating a properly terminated deflate stream, with a single deflate block marked as the last block. The only difference between the two streams is the first (least significant) bit, which is a 1 to mark the last block.

You do not say how the properly terminated deflate stream is "causing everything to fall apart". In any case, you can make a properly terminated deflate stream with `deflate_add` by using `ZLIB_FINISH` instead of `ZLIB_SYNC_FLUSH`, and forgoing the `substr`.

There is no way to make an invalid deflate stream with `gzdeflate`, if that's what you're asking. You can't just change the first bit, since for a larger string, the last block may not be the first block.